# difference between running a method before super.initState() and after super.initState()

Tags: flutter

what is the difference between running a method before `super.initState()` and after `super.initState()`

```
     @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();  
    getCurrentUser();   
  }



 @override
  void initState() {
 getCurrentUser(); 
    super.initState();  

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation for framework**: Dart is class based object oriented programming language, so when you build a widget you extend it from a base class `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget`. `initState` is lifecycle method in flutter widget (as you might know) which is only available to override in StatefulWidgets and it called only once. So, it call initState of base class which is StatefulWidget thats why you call `super.initState()`which in turn creates BuildContext and attached State.

**Now your question**: I didn't find anything different in calling a method before or after `super.initState()`. Event I tried adding `addPostFrameCallback` before `super.initState()` and it worked fine.
Even `super.mounted` is also true in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion**
Dart/Flutter documentation "suggests" to call super.initState() as first method before your body implementation.

But if we look at how it is implemented [Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

```
@protected
@mustCallSuper
void initState() {
  assert(_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created);
}
```

it's possible to see that it contains only an *assert()*. the assert built-in function it's called only in DEBUG mode, not in production mode. So, at the end of the day, it really doesn't matter, because the super.initState() would practically do nothing.